# Angular: how to access in TS a variable whose name is passed from HTML as a string

Tags: angular, eval

I want to access a variable in the .TS whose name is passed from HTML as a string.

Smth like:

HTML:

`<div id="myID"><button mat-button (click)="foo('name')">Export to Excel</button></div>`

TS

```
varName = VARIABLE_VALUES;

foo(x: any) void {
  ...I'd like to get an access to "this.x"

}
```

is there any way to evaluate the string  "this." + x?
or any other more elegant way to get an access to the variable whose name is passed as a string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) which is not directly related to Angular or Typescript but rather a JavaScript feature:

```
foo(x: any) void {
  // ...I'd like to get an access to "this.x"

  console.log(this[x]);
}
```